How can I understand the gambler's fallacy?
Let's imagine you roll a die 500 times. It's highly unlikely you would never roll a 6 in those 500 times, wouldn't you say?
But at the same time, each die roll is independent, there's only a 1/6th chance on average of rolling a 6.
So...is it true or false to expect your 501th roll is "less likely" to not be a 6? I'm just having trouble unraveling this.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Please read over this page, which seems pretty much to be a duplicate of your question. That page has 14 answers, one of which (at least) you might find explains this in a way that makes sense to you. If the rolls truly are all independent with a probability of 1/6 for each outcome, then the probability of a "6" at the 501st role is still 1/6. With only a $(5/6)^{500} =2.6 \times 10^{-40}$ probability of no "6" outcomes in 500 rolls, I'd suspect a die very heavily weighted against "6" instead.

I give a discussion (in a dice-rolling context) here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410383/805 -- the central point being that (given independence and a fair die) nothing acts to compensate for an excess or deficit of some outcome. While proportions will converge toward their expected values as the number of rolls grows, the raw counts don't compensate - they actually diverge.  The diagrams here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136879/805 (for many sets of tosses of a simulated coin) may clarify this distinction between convergence of the proportion and the non-convergence of the counts.
